# Use MySQL query result in a loop

Tags: mysql

I just started working with SQL and have been working with MySQL.I am trying to write a stored procedure that will take each value from my buyPrice column in my products table, and store each value into a variable. I then want it to multiply this variable by the sales tax and then take each result and place it into my empty sales_tax column. I would like to populate the whole column with the sales tax for each item. When I execute this method I get some error saying the productCode doesn't have a default value. **What is the proper way to write this? I know this isn't the most efficient way of doing this task, just trying to practice.**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE nFirstProcedure()
BEGIN
DECLARE IdValue, counter, holdValue, result INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE holdName VARCHAR(30); 
SET counter = 1; 
WHILE counter < ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products)
 DO
SET holdValue = (SELECT buyPrice FROM products WHERE sales_tax = null); 
SET result = (holdValue * 0.08);
INSERT INTO products (sales_tax) VALUES (result);

 END WHILE;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this with a loop.  Just use `update`:

```
update products
    set sales_tax = buyPrice * 0.08
    where sales_tax is null;
```

Comment: That's certainty a much more efficient way. I am practicing SQL and was trying to use variables and loops. What would I need to do to get it to store the buyPrice as a variable and then multiply the variable by the sales price and place it into the sales_tax? Thanks so much for your help